# C# interface implementation with derived interface

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, interface

In the following sample class "SomeClass" does not implement "ISomeInterface". Why can't I implement this by passing a more derived interface which does implement the base requirement. Whatever instance would be passed it would still implement the base, am I missing something?

```
namespace Test
{
    public interface IBaseInterface
    {
        void DoBaseStuff();
    }

    public interface IChildInterface : IBaseInterface
    {
        void DoChildStuff();
    }

    public interface ISomeInterface
    {
        void DoSomething(IBaseInterface baseInterface);
    }

    public class SomeClass : ISomeInterface
    {
        public void DoSomething(IChildInterface baseInterface)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This restriction exists because the `ISomeInterface` *expects* that any `IBaseInterface` will satisfy the contract. That is, if you have the following:

```
public interface IBase {}
public interface IChildA : IBase {}
public interface IChildB : IBase {}
```

And an interface that expects `IBase`:

```
public interface IFoo { void Bar(IBase val); }
```

Then restricting this in a derived class as you would like:

```
public class Foo : IFoo { public void Bar(IChildA val) {} }
```

Would create the following problem:

```
IChildB something = new ChildB();
IFoo something = new Foo();
something.Bar(something); // This is an invalid call
```

As such, you're not implementing the contract you said you would.

In this situation, you have two *simple* options:

- Adjust `IFoo` to be generic, and accept a `T` that is a derivation of `IBase`:

  ```
  public interface IFoo<T> where T : IBase { void Bar(T val); }
  public class Foo : IFoo<IChildA> { public void Bar(IChildA val) {} }
  ```

  Of course, this means that `Foo` can no longer accept *any* `IBase` (including `IChildB`).
- Adjust `Foo` to implement `IFoo`, with an additional utility method for `void Bar(IChildA val)`:

  ```
  public class Foo : IFoo
  {
      public void Bar(IBase val) {}
      public void Bar(IChildA val) {}
  }
  ```

  This has an interesting side-effect: whenever you call `((IFoo)foo).Bar` it will expect `IBase`, and when you call `foo.Bar` it will expect `IChildA` **or** `IBase`. This means it satisfies the contract, while also having your derived-interface-specific method. If you want to "hide" the `Bar(IBase)` method more, you could implement `IFoo` explicitly:

  ```
  void IFoo.Bar(IBase val) { }
  ```

  This creates *even more* inconsistent behavior in your code, as now `((IFoo)foo).Bar` is *completely* different from `foo.Bar`, but I leave the decision up to you.

  This means, with the second version in this section, that `foo.Bar(new ChildB());` is now invalid, as `IChildB` is *not* an `IChildA`.

---

> Why can't I implement this by passing a more derived interface which does implement the base requirement. Whatever instance would be passed it would still implement the base, am I missing something?

This is not allowed because of the reasoning I mentioned above, `IFoo.Bar` expects *any* `IBase`, whereas you want to *further* constrain the type to `IChildA`, which is *not* a super-interface of `IBase`, and even if it were it would not be allowed because it violates the interface implementation, though you could *more easily* define a second method at that point that does what you want.

Keep in mind that when you implement an `interface`, you subscribe to a *contract*, and C# will **not** let you violate that contract.

Comment: Great explanation and thank you for the workaround!

Answer (score 3):

This violates the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

`ISomeInterface` guarantees that the method can be called with *any* `IBaseInterface` instance.  Your implementation cannot limit that to only accept `IChildInterface` interfaces.

Comment: While this is true in a more general way I think the actual reason here is that the C# compiler simply requires a 1-to-1 implementation. If the situation was reversed (ie. interface required child interface, implementation allowed base interface) then it wouldn't violate Liskov but this is not legal either.

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/):

> When a class or struct implements an interface, the class or struct must provide an implementation for **all** of the members that the interface defines

This method in the derived

```
void DoSomething(IChildInterface baseInterface)
```

Does not have the same signature as the one in the interface:

```
void DoSomething(IBaseInterface baseInterface)
```

`IChildInterface` and `IBaseInterface` are not the same types. Therefore your derived class does not implement all methods of the interface and you get the compilation error.

For a possible the logic behind having this as a restriction instead of the compiler understanding the inheritance see Liskov's substitution principle as in SLakes answer

Answer (score 0):

If you could do that, then you could do this:

```
IAnimal cat = new Cat();
IAnimalTrainer dogTrainer = new DogTrainer();
dogTrainer.Train(cat);
```

An `IAnimalTrainer` can train any `IAnimal`.  But a `DogTrainer` can only train `Dog`s.  Thus it's illegal for `DogTrainer` to implement the `IAnimalTrainer` interface.

Answer (score 0):

You should change some interface to use some type which implements IBaseInterface,
then change the method signatures to use whichever child your SomeClass wants.

```
public interface ISomeInterface<TSomeChild> where TSomeChild : IBaseInterface
{
    void DoSomething(TSomeChild baseInterface);
}

public class SomeClass : ISomeInterface<IChildInterface>
{
    public void DoSomething(IChildInterface baseInterface)
    {
    }
}
```